# Is it possible to update preload files? (php, js or html code)

Tags: php, html, css

I'm using preload of CSS style on page with code like

```
<link rel="preload" href="<?php echo $cur_url; ?>css/styles.css" as="style" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Is it possible to update files that is already preloaded to user browser without asking user to clean cache? Because I have situation, that modal window is working correcty in anonymouse mode (when new/changed CSS files is loaded from server) of chrome mobile browser but in normal mode modal is not working, only one normal idea is cos of using old preloaded before CSS style from cache.
All other browsers working correctly, modal via bootstrap modal.
Thanks to all for any idea.

Comment: User doesn't need to clear the whole cache necessarily - hard reload of the page with Ctrl+F5 usually works.

Comment: Biggest problem, that 80% of my users browsing via mobile, and there is no Ctrl+F5

Comment: Ok well then it is definitely a two-step process to clear cache and then reload: https://browserhow.com/how-to-do-hard-refresh-and-reload-webpage-in-chrome-android/ . But from your description it sounds like you're not convinced this is definitely the issue? Have you tried it with one user, to be sure?

Comment: yep, i tested at all 3 my mobile devices(same bug with mobile chrome on android), without cleaning cache modal is not working, only in anonymouse mode, after erasing - everything is ok, but the problem is, is it possible to overwrite preloaded files with some js or php code(to update css) without asking user to delete cache?

Comment: No, it's not possible AFAIK. The user controls their own cache. You _could_ try setting a cache-control: no-cache header to be returned with your CSS/JS files from the server, which might force the browser to update from the server. But obviously you don't want to do that long-term really as it will degrade user's performance - although instead you could set a cache expiry date on it so that will always reload from the server eventually.